# Visual Studio Custom Item Template Dependent Upon

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-templates

I'm writing my own custom item template for use within visual studio. All is well except I need to find a way to get one of the files in the template to be dependent upon another.

In a csproj file it would look like this

```
<Compile Include="Class1.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Class1.xml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Does anybody have any idea how I would define this in the vstemplate file?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve this? I flagged this question for reopening because the duplicate actually isn't a duplicate, its another question.

Comment: Agree this is not a duplicate. This is about Item Templates, not just editing .proj files (as the other question relates to)

Comment: Please select the answer. the answer by @Yasin Kilicdere worked for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Test.cs</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs\$fileinputname$Dependent.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">TestDependent.cs</ProjectItem>
```

Comment: This answer wasn't selected as correct but I have tested it in VS2012 and it DOES work...

Comment: I tested in VS2012 it DOES work. It's the most simple and correct way.

Comment: Works on VS 2017 too

Comment: Note that this behavior was apparently not officially supported and no longer works in VS 16.5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can happen automatically for non-managed file types (i.e. file types that VS doesn't know about, like yours)...

A hack would be to use WizardExtensions (google for examples on writing a basic wizard) like this:

- Add the files initially as .cs and .designer.cs.
- Then use wizardExtensions to rename those files

or

- see if wizard extensions can directly modify the csproj (but that be difficult as VS might not let you do that without unloading the project first).

hope this helps...